# Optimizing Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

I Need to optimize my query it takes 36 sec to process it .
Pls help me out.
This is my query in oracle

```
Select  unique api_WEEKLY.country 
From api_WEEKLY INNER 
JOIN USERPROFILE ON api_WEEKLY.REGION  = NVL(USERPROFILE.REGION,api_WEEKLY.REGION) 
AND api_WEEKLY.Category = NVL(USERPROFILE.SECTOR,api_WEEKLY.Category) 
AND api_WEEKLY.MRP_DRP_CONTROLLER  = NVL(USERPROFILE.MRP_DRP_CONTROLLER,api_WEEKLY.MRP_DRP_CONTROLLER) 
AND api_WEEKLY.TDC_VAL = NVL(USERPROFILE.TDC_VAL,api_WEEKLY.TDC_VAL) 
AND api_WEEKLY.PLANT  = NVL(USERPROFILE.PLANT,api_WEEKLY.PLANT) 
AND api_WEEKLY.MATERIAL = NVL(USERPROFILE.MATERIAL,api_WEEKLY.MATERIAL) 
AND api_WEEKLY.SUBSECTOR  = NVL(USERPROFILE.SUBSECTOR,api_WEEKLY.SUBSECTOR) 
AND api_WEEKLY.COUNTRY = NVL(USERPROFILE.COUNTRY,api_WEEKLY.COUNTRY) 
WHERE USERPROFILE.USER_ID = 'sheikh.a' ;
```

and

[This is my USERPROFILE table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcKNO.png)

Comment: Using that NVL function might be forcing Oracle to do a table scan for every row in the table; indexes are useless.  Ask the database to EXPLAIN PLAN.  If you see TABLE SCAN, you have your answer.  You shouldn't have functions in WHERE clauses.

Comment: So i need to check every row of userprofile data with api file but can't find any solution . Do you suggest me some solution

Comment: I just did - ask Oracle to EXPLAIN PLAN.  You need to rewrite that query to take better advantage of indexes.

Comment: Okey. i ll check that. Thanks. can you suggest me any further step for taking * if the value is null and condition.

Comment: Yes, I'm guessing that the order matters a great deal here.  Think about how small the set of user id = 'sheikh.a' is.  If you did that first and then did the JOIN, you'd be asking the query engine to do a lot less work.  Filter first, then JOIN.  Don't have to worry about NVL that way.

Comment: So first i write ON USERPROFILE.USER_ID = 'sheikh.a' Then write AND condition.

Comment: can i write it like this   Select  unique a.country From api_WEEKLY a INNER JOIN USERPROFILE u ON u.USER_ID = 'sheikh.a' WHERE UPI_WEEKLY.REGION  = NVL(USERPROFILE.REGION,UPI_WEEKLY.REGION) AND UPI_WEEKLY.Category = NVL(USERPROFILE.SECTOR,UPI_WEEKLY.Category)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace the `NVL` functions you can try:

```
From api_WEEKLY a
     INNER JOIN
     USERPROFILE u
     ON  ( u.REGION IS NULL OR a.REGION = u.REGION ) 
     AND ( u.SECTOR IS NULL OR a.Category = u.SECTOR )

     ... 

WHERE u.USER_ID = 'sheikh.a'
```

Comment: And what about WHERE USERPROFILE.USER_ID = 'sheikh.a' ;

Comment: Append it to the query as normal.

Comment: I try that it takes less time than before but that is also a huge time

Answer (score 1):

I'd work it in steps.  Start with:

```
Select a.country 
From api_WEEKLY INNER as a, userprofile as u
where u.user_id = 'sheikh.a'
and a.country = u.country
```

Be an experimentalist.

Comment: hmm  but suppose if a row only contains region name then i have to select all the data in remaining 7 columns and then check for the Unique country from all rows that are fetched.

Comment: That user id ought to narrow it down very quickly.  all you have to do it check those other tables against values in THAT user profile row.  You could pare those down by subselecting against those rows that have the interesting bits.  One question: Why all the NULLs?  Sounds like a cumbersome design.